# Oracle 10: how to link for using Oracle 10 with ASP.NET MVC 2, VS 2010, and Microsoft IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, installation

We have a wonderful ASP.NET MVC 2 web application using MS SQL 2008 and VS 2010.  The customer wants to use Oracle 10g as a back end database.  I want to point our MVC2 app to it and run our tests.  I have no clue where to start with Oracle 10g.

Anyone have a how-to link on how to setup an Oracle 10g database and use it in place of SQL 2008 above for testing?  I assume Oracle has some sort of Developer edition like Microsoft has SQL Express.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's equivalent to Microsoft SQL Express is [Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html). But I don't think it will be easy for you to migrate your application to use OracleXE instead of MSSQLServer Express.

If you are using LinQ to SQL, you don't have Oracle support. If you are using Entity Framework, you have Oracle third party support (although an official support for Oracle is supposed to be on its way).

ADO.NET provider will be different.

And of course, you won't have 100% data type equivalence.

So I wish you good luck, and if you have the possibility, convince your client to use SQLServer Express or be prepared to migrate a lot of your app.